# np.linalg.solve is not giving correct result

Tags: python, scipy, linear-algebra

I tried to parameterize an arbitrary t vector with given bases ss with function  [linalg.solve](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solve.html):

```
t = np.array([0.4, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.3, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.2, 0., 0., 0.1])
ss = np.array([[1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
           [0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
           [0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.],
           [1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0., -0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0., -1.],
           [0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0., -0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -0.],
           [0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1., -0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0., -0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0., -0.],
           [1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1., -0.,  0., -1.],
           [0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -0., -1.,  0., -0.],
           [0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -0.,  0.,  1., -0.],
           [1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0., -0.,  0., -1., -0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

then do:

```
para = sp.linalg.solve(ss, t)

print para

print np.dot(ss, para) == t
```

I got:

[ 0.175  0.    -0.     0.15  -0.     0.    -0.     0.125  0.    -0.    -0.15  0.     0.025 -0.     0.     0.075]

[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True False]

Clearly it is not right... Why this False happens?

Comment: i get a a singular matrix error when i run your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's a rounding/numerical-approximation error:

```
t[-1]
Out[493]: 0.10000000000000001

np.dot(ss,para)[-1]
Out[495]: 0.099999999999999964
```

Comment: Is there any other substitute method?

Comment: I found what happened. ss should be transposed to find the correct parameters. Thanks anyway.